# Problems writing an integer to binary file C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream

I am using fstream to write an integer to binary file.

```
int main(){

fstream f1;
int num = 2, num2 = 0;

f1.open("dat1", ios::app | ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);

f1.write((char *)num, sizeof(int));
f1.seekp(0);
f1.read((char *)num2, sizeof(int));

cout << num2;

}
```

The problem is on line f1.write. I can write to binary file an array, but when I try to write just one block of int it gives me an error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x522C7EA6 (msvcp120d.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.**

I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast the *address* of `num` to `char*`, not `num` itself. In fact, the behaviour of using the result of `(char*)num` is *undefined* which explains the crash.

Use `f1.write((char *)&num, sizeof(num));` instead. Change `f1.read` similarly.

I've also changed the `sizeof` argument: I prefer that style as it future-proofs you against type changes. Moving on, you'll need to consider *endianness* if you're writing and reading in different platforms (e.g. Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
f1.write((char *)&num, sizeof(int));
f1.seekp(0);
f1.read((char *)&num2, sizeof(int));
```

`write()` and `read()` want a pointer to where your data is.

```
int num = 2;
```

Using `(char *)num` converts `num` to a pointer pointing at address `0x00000002`.

---

Also, when working with binary files (other than testing) it is always best to include a header, which should at least contain the following:

- A [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) (usually 4 bytes), so the exact file type can be determined or checked regardless of what the extention might be.
- A version number, which will allow you to extend the format and structure of your file in the future without breaking your current format.
- As others already stated, a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which will allow your data to be read in correctly on all platforms (Little-endian / Big-endian).

Answer (score 2):

The line should actually be:

```
f1.write((char *)&num, sizeof(int));
```

You need an **address** as an argument to the `write` function.
Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/.

Comment: Also one needs to consider the byte oder in order to use the file in a platform independent manner if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`write` want's a array. This means the start address. `(char *)num` this converts the number to a address and will point to a point you don't want. Use `&num` to get the address of `num`. Maybe make a cast with `(char*)` too.